# Container Connection Refused

Tags: python, docker, plotly

I am new to Docker.
Here is a very simple application written in DashPlotly:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 install --no-cache -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8050
CMD ["python3","./app.py","--host","0.0.0.0"]



#docker build -t test .  
#docker run -p 8051:8050 -it test

Connecting to the PostgreSQL database...   
Running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/
Debugger PIN: 479-458-364
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
```

But when a point the browser to 127.0.0.1:8051, it says connection reset...

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to force the DashPlotly server to run on 0.0.0.0

```
  app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0',debug=False, port=8050)
```